# Execute a method inside Eventhandler with delay and ignore th next eventhandler during this interval

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, event-handling, delay

I have a textbox filter which is binded to the following event handler

```
 SimpleFilterTextBox.TextChanged += OnFilterTextBoxTextChangedHandler;

 private void OnFilterTextBoxTextChangedHandler(object oSender, TextChangedEventArgs oArgs)

 {

  //Other operations
  _oCollectionView.Filter = new Predicate<object>(DoFilter);
 }
```

I want the DoFilter to be called after the first character is pressed and wait for 1 sec( in case the user enters another character during this time). Don't call the method DoFilter during this gap. And the same for the third and further on.

The problem here I face is the second character is handled in a new handler, how can I make it to accept 2 or more characters with the given delay.

Answer (score 0):

Use `async` and `CancellationToken`.

```
private void OnFilterTextBoxTextChangedHandler(object oSender, TextChangedEventArgs oArgs)
{
    //Other operations
    _oCollectionView.Filter = new Predicate<object>(DoFilter);
}
private CancellationTokenSource filterToken;
private async void DoFilter(object parameter)
{
    CancellationTokenSource localToken;
    try
    {
        if (this.filterToken != null)
            this.filterToken.Cancel();

        this.filterToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
        localToken = this.filterToken;

        await Task.Delay(1000, localToken.Token);

        // Your logic
    }
    catch (TaskCanceledException) {}
    catch (Exception e) { // Other Exceptions }
    finally
    {
        localToken.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: I try return a bool in my DoFilter method not void, I tried to use Task<bool> in my method however its fails at _oCollectionView.Filter = new Predicate<object>(DoFilter); saying it has the wrong return type. Any suggestions